# UIScrollView Cutting off lables at the top of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, label

I am displaying multiple labels inside a UIScrollView, I can get them to display and I can get them to scroll, but a label at the top of the screen is cut off and is not visible unless you pull down. I have a tried adjusting the UIScrollViews content size, frame etc. all to no avail. Please help! Code:

```
    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    int scrollWidth = 120;
    int scrollHeight = 1000;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,scrollHeight);
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the contentOffset to (0,0).

Comment: For me it was a contentoffset issue too but 0,0 did not work for me; I had to set it to -ve amount of my scrollview's Y to make it work. Not sure why?